# Print and compare structure comprising two integers

Tags: c++, beginner

The question is from: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/member-functions/

> Create a struct called `IntPair` that holds two integers. Add a member function named `print` that prints the value of the two integers

Here's the code I have written, with `main()` already provided for exercising the `struct`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

/* Question:
 * Create a struct called IntPair that holds two integers. Add a member function
 * named print that prints the value of the two integers.
 */

struct IntPair {
    int a {};
    int b {};

    void print() {
        std::cout << a << " " << b << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    IntPair p1 {1, 2};
    IntPair p2 {3, 4};

    std::cout << "p1: ";
    p1.print();

    std::cout << "p2: ";
    p2.print();
}
```

And here's the output:

```
p1: 1 2
p2: 3 4
```

It was followed up with another question:

> Add a new member function to `IntPair` named `isEqual` that returns a Boolean indicating whether one `IntPair` is equal to another.

Here's the code I wrote for it, with the `main()` already provided:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

/* Question:
 * Add a new member function to IntPair named isEqual that returns a Boolean 
 * indicating whether one IntPair is equal to another.
 */

struct IntPair {
    int a {};
    int b {};

    void print() {
        std::cout << a << " " << b << "\n";
    }

    bool isEqual(const IntPair& ip) {
        return a == ip.a && b  == ip.b;
    }
};

int main()
{
    IntPair p1 {1, 2};
    IntPair p2 {3, 4};

    std::cout << "p1: ";
    p1.print();

    std::cout << "p2: ";
    p2.print();

    std::cout << "p1 and p1 " << (p1.isEqual(p1) ? "are equal\n" : "are not equal\n");
    std::cout << "p1 and p2 " << (p1.isEqual(p2) ? "are equal\n" : "are not equal\n");
}
```

And here's the output:

```
p1: 1 2
p2: 3 4
p1 and p1 are equal
p1 and p2 are not equal
```

### Review Request:

Anything. Everything.

Comment: This felt like a C `struct` on steroids.